# junit4 output interpretation

Tags: junit, junit4, junit3

My console output from running JUnit in `cmd.exe` looks like:

```
JUnit version 4.10
.....I
Time: 0,469


OK (5 tests)
```

What does the `I` on the second line mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the test has been [@Ignored](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Ignore.java).

Comment: which test? I ignored a unit test on purpose to see if the number of `I`'s would increase and got `I....I`

Comment: In the example you gave, it's the sixth one. The output from JUnit Core isn't very verbose :-). Seriously, most of the time you'll run your tests through an IDE.

Comment: Why does it say 5 tests, when there are 6 incl. one Ignored?